# Prevent memory abuse

Tags: python, memory, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have Flask web application with the view function, that take some get arguments. So this is the code of the view:

```
@bp.route('/recent')
def recent():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    torrents = Torrent.query.filter_by(approved=True).paginate(page, 
current_app.config['TORRENTS_PER_PAGE'], False)
    return render_template('torrents/recent.html', torrents=torrents.items)
```

First problem: `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER` when page is a large number. I can solve this with try/except block, but will it be right?

And the second: when I pass extremely large numbers to this view, the memory that application uses increases by 5MB every request. I can just hold F5 key and run out of memory. How can I fix this?

Comment: _"I can solve this with try/except block, but will it be right?"_ I think that depends very much on what you put in the `except` block. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @Kevin, the simplest thing I could think of was `abort(400)`

Comment: Hmm, not an unreasonable approach... What happens if you don't set paginate's third argument to False? Maybe letting `error_out` retain its default value will make it handle your cases in a useful way.

Comment: I set it to True, but it's still OverflowError..

Comment: Largest SQLite int is 8 byte, but in Python3 int is unbound and can be bigger than 8 byte and cause overflow. Why don't you store it as a string?

Comment: _hold F5 key and run out of memory_ There is almost no way to solve this without seeing whole code. `memory_profiler` lib helped me a few times to solve memory leaks.

Comment: @Fian, this large int isn't a column, it's a argument that I pass to paginate function

Comment: I think it's fine to catch errors related to too-large ints, or to check for them ahead of time. If SQLite can handle 8 byte ints, then your application should be able to reach page 18446744073709551616 with no trouble. It seems unlikely to me that your application will require more pages than that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the first problem solved. And what do you think about the second?